# Intercepting a form submission in a Chrome content extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to intercept the submission of a form on a particular website. The form has no ID, but it does have a name. I'd prefer not to use jQuery, as my extension is very light weight and has no dependencies. The form is not submitted by a button, but by the submit() method.

I thought I could just handle the onSubmit event, but it doesn't seem to get raised.

Now I'm stumped, any ideas?

Comment: `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` are for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch your form with

`var myForm = document.getElementsByName('myForm');`

Which returns a `nodeList` (similar to `Array`). Then you can override the `submit` event in two ways:

`myForm.onsubmit = function (evt) {...};`

or

`myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {...});`

Be careful to only use lowercase letters for the event name. With the second example you can bind multiple listeners to the event but it isn't supported by older browsers (< IE 9).

Example:

html:

```
<form name="myForm" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

js:

```
var myForm;

myForm = document.getElementsByName('myForm')[0];

myForm.onsubmit = function (evt) {
    // Do things here before passing on or stop the submit
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but the second part of the answer did not work. I have posted a workaround which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my content.html:

```
var patch = document.createElement('script');  
patch.src= chrome.extension.getURL('patch.js')
document.body.appendChild(patch);

document.forms['logoutForm'].onsubmit = function() {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({logout: true});
}
```

In patch.js:

```
document.logoutForm.submitOrig = document.logoutForm.submit;

document.logoutForm.submit = function() {

    this.onsubmit();

    this.submitOrig();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selector for each element.
For example, if you have a textarea and form, you can access to the form data like this below.

## HTML

```
<form class="my-form">
  <textarea
    id="myTextArea"
  />
  <button 
    type="submit"
    class="my-button" 
    id="myButton">
      Button
  </button>
</form>
```

## JS

```
const myButton = document.querySelector("#myButton")
myButton.addEventListener("click", async() => {
  const form = document.querySelector("form.my-form")
  const textarea = document.querySelector("#myTextArea")
})
```