# Listen for submit event in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a simple chrome extension that listens for submit on a certain webpage (also build by me). However, this is my first chrome extension and I can't find any good documentation/explanation on how to do this.

For the sake of simplicity, imagine this is my page:

> ```
> <html>
> <head> 
> </head>
> <body>
> <form onclick="main()">
> <textarea id="source">Text Entry.</textarea>
> <input type="submit"  id="buttons">Generate</input>
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

This is the manifest.json I wrote:

```
{
  "name": "Awesome name",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Extension to listen for submit.",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
 {
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["inject.js"]
}
 ],
 "permissions": [
  "tabs"
 ]

}
```

How would I go from here? I wrote some script, but they didn't seem to work :(

Comment: What does "didn't seem to work" mean? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist to avoid playing the 20-questions game in helping answer your question.

Comment: donot used inline script in chrome extensions .... go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470379/intercepting-a-form-submission-in-a-chrome-content-extension